# onclick of a list item display the image and on second click on the same gives the value

Tags: javascript

```js
print=console.log;
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { elements[i].onclick = show; }

function show(event) {
 var targetnode = event.target;
 var element = targetnode.firstChild;
 print("target is", targetnode);
 print("child node is", element);
 displayOnPage(element); //print(targetnode.childNodes[0]);
}
function displayOnPage(element) {
 var value = element;
 print("the value is to function came is", value);
 var onPage = document.getElementById("photoFrame");

 if (!onPage.hasChildNodes()) {
  onPage.appendChild(value);
 } else Replace(onPage, value); //print("the value here is", value);
}
function Replace(onPage, image) {
 img = image;
 page = onPage;
 page.removeChild(page.childNodes[0]);
 page.appendChild(img);
 print("the value came to page is", img);

}
```

```css
.menu{width:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;height:50px;}

    ul{list-style:none;padding:0;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;line-height:2em;
    display: block;}

    ul li a{text-decoration: none; color: white; display:block;}

    ul 
    li{float:left;width:200px;background-color:black;opacity:0.6;text-align: center; 
    color: white;}

    ul li li:hover{background-color: red;}

    ul li ul li{display: none;}

    ul li:hover ul li{display: block;}

    ul li img{display: none;}

    .inner{height:150px;width:80%;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;}

    #photoFrame {width:80%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head><title>photo frame</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="menu">
    <div class="inner">
    <ul >
    <li>Mountains
     <ul>
     <li class="list"><img src="img/mountainsOne.jpg" alt="image1" width="500" height="400"/>Mount Everest</li>
     <li class="list"><img src="img/mountainsTwo.jpg" alt="image2" width="500" height="400"/>Himalayas</li>
     <li class="list"><img src="img/mountainsThree.jpg" alt="image3" width="500" height="400"/>Mount Perk</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="rivers"> 
    <li>Rivers
     <ul>
     <li class="list"><img src="img/riversOne.jpg" alt="image4" width="500" height="400"/>Ganga</li>
     <li class="list"><img src="img/riversTwo.jpg" alt="image4" width="500" height="400"/>krishna</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="lakes">
    <li>Lakes
     <ul>
     <li class="list"><img src="img/lakesOne.jpg" alt="image5" width="500" height="400"/>Tungabhadra</li>
     <li class="list"><img src="img/lakesTwo.jpg" alt="image5" width="500" height="400"/>kaveri</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="photoFrame" ></div>
    </div>
    <script src="photoAlbum.js" >
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So what's your question? Are you aware that `print` in JS actually tries to _print_ a sheet of paper? Try `console.log()` instead

Comment: the problem when ever I click the item the corresponding image is shown and on the second click it gives the value other than the image

Comment: yes I assign the console.log to "print" so console.log() is same as print()

Comment: Could you then please update your snippet, because currently it is unusable. It tries to print sheets of paper

Comment: Hi Jeremy I have updated the code in  answer,kindly go through it

Comment: You should have updated your original question, rather than writing an answer and repeating your code in it. I have edited your question for you, so you can delete this answer. I had a look at your code, you're actually _moving_ the HTML image out of the menu into another location on click. So when you click again, there's no more image to move, so it moves the menu element itself. It would keep moving parents element if there were more. I don't think that's the way to go :) Why don't you just read the `src` attribute of the image, and set it to another image?

Comment: thank you so much for editing,and  could you please explain me that how I'm moving the element,my moto is to fetch the firstChild of the target node as image is inside  a list,img would be the obvious first child and fetching the child node and appending it to the container for display, I came up  with the setAttribute and when ever a click happened adding the element "img" and attribute "src"

Comment: Well that's not how you di it. You _read_ the `src` attribute of the image `myURL = firstElement.attributes.src` or something), so that gives you a URL, and then you set that URL to another image (`secondElement.attributes.src = myURL`, something like that). This is just a hint, don't expect this code to work right away, but you get the idea.